# Vuforia AR object is flickering on eyewear but not on phone

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, augmented-reality, vuforia, multitargeting

I'm trying to get an object to show up with Vuforia in Unity by using a multi target object.

So far this works, but only on my Android phone, but not on the AR glasses.

On the AR glasses, it shows up as this:[image]
It's flickering a lot.

I tried changing camera clipping plane values, different shaders, etc. - the issue goes away if I use ZTest Always in my shader (but ZTest Always causes other issues so I can't use that).

So what might be the difference in rendering here which causes the flickering on the glasses, but not on the phone, when both use Android?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using a renderer that isnt native to your glasses, you should check what renderer your glasses use and use that instead